# How to use OpenCV Stitcher class with Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV Stitcher class with Python, with no luck. My code is:

```
import cv2
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
foo = cv2.imread("foo.png")
bar = cv2.imread("bar.png")
result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))
```

I get a tuple with (1, None).

Following the C++ example, I tried to pass a numpy array as a second argument to stitch() with no luck.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. I do not find any python documentation for this function, though it is there.

Answer (score 22):

You're using it right, be the process failed for some reason.

The first value of the result tuple is an error code, with 0 indicating success. Here you got 1, which means, according to `stitching.hpp`, that the process needs more images.

```
enum Status
{
    OK = 0,
    ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS = 1,
    ERR_HOMOGRAPHY_EST_FAIL = 2,
    ERR_CAMERA_PARAMS_ADJUST_FAIL = 3
};
```

`ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS` usually indicates that you don't have enough keypoints in your images.

If you need more details about why the error occurs, you could switch to C++ and debug the process in details.

---

Edit : providing working example

Same code as OP, just added result save and absolute paths.

```
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
foo = cv2.imread("D:/foo.png")
bar = cv2.imread("D:/bar.png")
result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))

cv2.imwrite("D:/result.jpg", result[1])
```

with these images: (I hope you love koalas)

foo.png

[image: foo.png]

bar.png

[image: bar.png]

result.jpg

[image: result.jpg]

Comment: Gwen, thanks for taking interest in that problem. We want to have a python solution, can you give an example in python with images you provide?

Comment: Does not work for me yet, have demonstrated my problems with separate answer above. Can you help?

Comment: I can't comment your answer (not enough reputation...).

There is a bug in OpenCV 3.0+. It remains quite unclear but seems to be linked to OpenCL integration (see [this bug report](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5667) for example).

You need to rebuild OpenCV without OpenCL support, and maybe comment line 163 of `cv2.cpp` (`//CV_Error(Error::StsAssert, "The data should normally be NULL!");`)

Comment: @tfv and I'm using python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.1.0 too.

Comment: OK, I'll have to look into that in more detail tonight. Commenting my post should be working now :-)

Comment: Yay, thanks :-)  If you can't rebuild OpenCV 3.1, you could try to downgrade to a previous version (2.4.12) where the bug is not present.

Comment: as described above: Tried it with 2.4.11, result is: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createStitcher'. So only way seems compilation. Can you confirm that it works for your with your code above and binary version of 2.4.12?

Comment: No, I didn't try with 2.4, that was just an idea.

Comment: That's a Koala Bear! Also the bug which causes error on line 163, seems to be resolved in OpenCV 3.3.0. Thanks for the well written answer.