# How to stitch images from a UAV using opencv python with Stitcher class

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-stitching

I was searching for the  Stitcher class in OpenCV Python which will help me to stitch the images which I collect from the UAV. I was following the method shown in this link 
[How to use OpenCV Stitcher class with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362922/how-to-use-opencv-stitcher-class-with-python)
Unfortunately this is throwing some errors in OpenCV 3.1 and Python 2.7. I didn't find any appropriate Opencv docs for this function. Could anyone please help me in this. 
It would be highly apperciated if someone is able to explain the stitcher class using python.
`    import cv2

```
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
foo = cv2.imread("Image1")
bar = cv2.imread("Image2")
result = stitcher.stitch((Image1,Image2))

cv2.imshow("stitch_image",result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362922/how-to-use-opencv-stitcher-class-with-python), I believe you need to do the following:

```
cv2.imshow("stitch_image",result[1])
```