# How to Set Panorama Mode in OpenCV Python Stitcher Class?

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching

Based on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362922/how-to-use-opencv-stitcher-class-with-python), I have been trying to use OpenCV's Stitcher class in python. My code is basically the same as in the answer.

```
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
foo = cv2.imread("D:/foo.png")
bar = cv2.imread("D:/bar.png")
result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))

cv2.imwrite("D:/result.jpg", result[1])
```

The issue is I want to change the mode from Panoramic to Scans. [In the c++ documentation,](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html) the create method has an input of mode. However, the createStitcher class in Python only takes one input- whether or not to try gpu. Is there a way to specify the mode in Python?

When I tried createStitcherScans, I get an error

```
stitcher = cv2.createStitcherScans(False)
"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createStitcherScans'"
```

I did find [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/10681) that seems relevant, regarding Python bindings missing something. But this is over my head and I am not sure how to edit the opencv code to do this properly. I tried adding this to the stitching.hpp:

```
typedef Stitcher::Mode Mode;
```

But nothing happened. createStitcher(1, False) still give me the attribute error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this would also interesting for me, did you get a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved in Open CV 4 (at least in 4.1.0 which I'm running). You can now specify `mode` as a keyword argument to `cv2.Stitcher.create`:

```
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(mode = 1)
```

It seems that the enumeration labels for the different modes have not yet been ported but it works with numbers. `PANORAMA` is `0`, `SCANS` is `1` as defined [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.1.0/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching.hpp).

Note, if you're working on Google Colab then you can change the version of Open CV like this:

```
!pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. After looking at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#acb32106b3b3e7870d4b39082ab58a26e) it looks like the python wrapper function is not mapping to create(), but rather createDefault() which does not have a mode input, only the try_use_gpu input. I don't have experience with wrappers, but one could try to figure it out by reading [OpenCV's info on how the python bindings work](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html).

based on my work with stitch so far in python, it seems like createDefault() creates a stitcher in PANORAMA mode since it is warping my images. I can't dedicate work time to looking through the wrappers, but if I end up spending personal time to fix it, I will update my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official test code for Python on GitHub [`samples/python/stitching.py`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stitching.py), you can use **`Stitcher_PANORAMA`** or **`Stitcher_SCANS`**. You can always check the test code of any module, like [`modules/stitching/misc/python/test`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/stitching/misc/python/test/test_stitching.py) in this case.

```py
stitcher = cv.Stitcher.create(cv.Stitcher_PANORAMA)
```