# OpenCV Stitcher class not working in Python, always returns ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to use the OpenCV Stitcher class for putting two images together. I ran the simple example provided in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362922/how-to-use-opencv-stitcher-class-with-python) with the same koala images, but it returns `(1, None)` every time. I've tried this on opencv-python version 3.4, 4.2, and 4.4, and all have the same result.

I've tried replacing the stitcher initializer with something else, (`cv2.Stitcher.create`, `cv2.Stitcher_create`, `cv2.createStitcher`), but nothing seems to work. If it helps, I'm on Mac Catalina, using Python 3.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the default pano confidence threshold using `setPanoConfidenceThresh()`. By default it's 1.0, and apparently it results in the stitcher thinking that it has failed.

Here is the full example that works for me. I used that pair of koala images as well, and I am on opencv 4.2.0:

```
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(cv2.Stitcher_PANORAMA)
stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.0) # might be too aggressive for real examples
foo = cv2.imread("/path/to/image1.jpg")
bar = cv2.imread("/path/to/image2.jpg")
status, result = stitcher.stitch((foo,bar))
assert status == 0 # Verify returned status is 'success'
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I think in this particular case `cv2.Stitcher_SCANS` is a better mode (transformation between images is just a translation), but either `SCANS` or `PANORAMA` works.

Comment: Almost worked, got it to output something by using `Stitcher_SCANS` and setting pano confidence threshold to 0.0. However, it always outputs one one or the other image, and not any overlap. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Try rescaling the images to 0.6 and 0.6 , by using the resize. For some reason I got the result only at those values.